# How to get more information about generalized binomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

I am reading about generalized binomial series in *Concrete Mathematics* by Knuth,and **FEW** documents exist on the Internet(including wikipedia).What should I do to find more resources?If anyone could help,I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Exactly what is the snag for you? Knuth is prone to come up with his own definititons and techniques, which not always take the world by storm. Perhaps there are other techniques in use in this area? Other names?

Comment: In particular, in the comments to an answer there, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuss%E2%80%93Catalan_number) article is linked, and in the bibliography of Concrete Mathematics it references Lambert's paper "Observationes variae in Mathesin puram". By looking at papers that cite this paper you can likely find more information